# Rails namespaces with only numbers

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, api

I'm building an api in rails, and I have been told that I need to scope the site so it has versions.

Something like `/1.0/do_something`.

From what I've read, I do this by making a routes.rb that looks like the following:

```
API::Application.routes.draw do
   scope :path => "1.0", :module => "1.0" do
      post "do_something" => "controller#method"

      # Everything else. Glob is saved in params[:r]
      match '*r', :to => 'errors#e404'
   end 
end
```

But when I `rake routes`, I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
missing :action
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not what you're looking for, but [grape](https://github.com/intridea/grape) might make things easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have a module called "1.0" for obvious reasons. Consider calling this `V1` instead.

Comment: If you could, referencing it would be a problem. `1.0.do_method` would actually call `Float#do_method`

Comment: What if I needed to map that url to a module? I'm relatively new to rails.

Comment: @icco: Then you would do `scope :path => "1.0", :module => "V1" do`. Simple.